# Insert JSON data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I tried to insert it to MySQL Base but its not work for me, please help to solve this.
This is how  JSON looks like:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "response": {
        "Aviator Goggles": {
        "price": 1009,
        "quantity": 269
    },
    "Aviator Sunglasses": {
        "price": 460,
        "quantity": 187
    },
    "BIKER CRATE": {
        "price": 29,
        "quantity": 3569
    }
 },
    "time": 1524852778
}
```

My php code to parse and insert the data:

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetAllLowestListPrices/v1/?appid=578080&format=json_pretty";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r ($data);

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("pubg") or die(mysql_error());

foreach($data as $item) {

       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `c5f` (response, price, quantity) 
       VALUES ('".$item['response']."','".$item['price']."','".$item['quantity']."')") or die(mysql_error());
     }
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: Thiis is tagged `mysqli` but you're clearly not using that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the decoded json (`print_r($data)`), you will see this:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [response] => Array
        (
            [Aviator Goggles] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 1009
                    [quantity] => 269
                )

            [Aviator Sunglasses] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 460
                    [quantity] => 187
                )

            [BIKER CRATE] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 29
                    [quantity] => 3569
                )

        )

    [time] => 1524852778
)
```

To do your database insert (I am replicating your mysql calls here but you really should upgrade, at the very least to [MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) but in my opinion [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) is better and also to using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)), you need to iterate through `$data['response']`:

```
foreach ($data['response'] as $key => $item) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `c5f` (response, price, quantity) 
        VALUES ('$key','{$item['price']}','{$item['quantity']}')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO for inserting data into your database; here is some example code:

```
// Set these to your login data
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'pubg');

// We connect to the database using the values above
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
// We tell PDO to report us every error
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Now we prepare a query
$sql = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `c5f` SET `response` = :response, `price` = :price, `quantity` = :quantity;');

// We can use $sql to insert data
$data = $response['data'];
foreach($data as $key => $item)
    $sql->execute(array(
        ':response' => $key,
        ':price'    => $item['price'],
        ':quantity' => $item['quantity']
    ));
    echo 'Insert: '. htmlentities($key) .' ('. $item['quantity'] .' - '. $item['price'] .')'."\r\n";
}
```

This will connect to the database, prepare your insert statement and execute it for every dataset.